# Regular Expression for a string contains if characters all in capital python

Tags: python, regex, pypdf

I'm extracting textual paragraph followed by text like "OBSERVATION #1" or "OBSERVATION #2" in the output from library like PyPDF2.
However there would be some error so it could be like "OBSERVA'TION #2" and I have to avoid like "Suite #300" so the rule is **"IF THERE IS CHARACTER, IT WOULD BE IN CAPITAL".**
Currently the python code snippet like

```
inspection_observation=pdfFile.getPage(z).extractText()
                if 'OBSERVATION' in inspection_observation:
                    for finding in re.findall(r"[OBSERVATION] #\d+(.*?) OBSERVA'TION #\d?", inspection_observation, re.DOTALL):

                    #print inspection_observation;
                        print finding;
```

Please advise the appropriate regular expression for this instance,

Comment: Is "SUITE #300" valid? Or do you only want "OBSERVATION #X" ?

Comment: I only need LIKE "OBSERVATION #X" since they are all in capital. There will be no "SUITE" but only "Suite" in the text.

Comment: a sample would be helpful

Comment: Something could be like this "Central Expressway Suite #300 Dallas, TX 75204 (214) 253-5200 Industry Information: www.fda.gov/oc/indusuy OATE(S) OF INSPECTION 11/5-8/ 18 FEINUMBER . ...OBSERVATION #1 Your firm produced highly potent drugs without providing adequate cleaning ofwork surfaces and utensils to prevent cross-contamination. Specifically. 4(b) < A.>drug products ...Your firm has no evidence to show that your cleaning procedures can adequately remove residual drug products or detergent. OBSERVA'TION #2 Non-pharmaceutical"

Comment: @MichaelC.H.Wang Perhaps `(?=[A-Z']*[A-Z])[A-Z']+\s+#\d+(.*?(?=[A-Z']*[A-Z][A-Z']*\s+#\d+|$))` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yeCcS4/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there should be a capital and the word can contain a `'`, you could use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) where you can list the characters that are allowed and a positive lookahead.

Then you can capture the content between those capital words and use a positive lookahead to check if what follows is another capital word followed by `#` and 1+ digits or the end of the string. This regex makes use of `re.DOTALL` where the dot matches a newline.

```
(?=[A-Z']*[A-Z])[A-Z']+\s+#\d+(.*?(?=[A-Z']*[A-Z][A-Z']*\s+#\d+|$))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?=[A-Z']*[A-Z])` Positive lookahead to assert what follows at least a char A-Z where a `'` can occur before
- `[A-Z']+\s+#\d+` match 1+ times A-Z or ', 1+ whitespace characters and 1+ digits
- `(` Capture group

  - `.*?` Match any character
  - `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what follows is

    - `[A-Z']*[A-Z][A-Z']*` Match uppercase char A-Z where a `'` can be before and after
    - `\s+#\d+` Match 1+ whitespace chars, # and 1+ digits or the end of the string
  - `)` Close non capture group
- `)` Close capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J8Yrqu/1)